Firefox does not accept a website with self-signed certificate
I'm trying to show the content of this website :
https://wiki.supreme-gamers.com/bigdroid
because there should be a tutorial about how to compile Android DarkMatter. Unfortunately I'm not able to visit it because it still say that's not secure since it contains a self-signed certificate. I tried several methods to bypass the limitation,like explained here :
Let Firefox accept a website with self-signed certificate
It seems that the exceptions that I put are ignored.
exceptions ignored
Please help. thanks.


It seems that the exceptions that I put are ignored.

It's because those are not the same certificate. If you look closely, the web server generates a different certificate every time and as Firefox exceptions are key-based (i.e. they don't disable validation entirely but rather switch to "SSH style" validation for that site), they will never work for that site because the next connection will have a new certificate again.
Though even if you found a way to add a server-based exception, that wouldn't do you any good because the server doesn't really respond to HTTP requests anyway (neither with TLS nor without), immediately closing the connection as soon as it receives one.
Use an archived copy of the site.
